# Scala - How to extract all objects inside a map of maps to a new map?

Tags: scala

I have to following map in scala

```
mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, App]]()
```

Assuming App contains a field called Token which is not the key for the inner map.

What is the best practice to extract a map of  from this nested map.

I did

```
val result =  mutable.Map[String, AppKey]()
myMap foreach(x=>x._2 foreach(y=>result.put(y._2.token, y._2)))
```

Comment: Are the `token`s in your original Map distinct?  If not, for a given `token` only one of the corresponding `App`s will be in the result Map (since Map keys are always distinct).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `flatmap` and `map`:

```
val result = myMap.flatMap { case (_, mp) => mp.map { case (_, app) => app.token -> app }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding properly, the keys of the resulting map should be the tokens and the values should be the `AppKey`s, and you throw away the keys of the original maps.

As noted in the other answer, `map` (or actually `flatMap`) would be the more usual choice here:

```
val result = myMap.flatMap{ case (_, v) => v.map{ case (_, ak) => ak.token -> ak }}
  .toMap
```

The inner `map` extracts the key-value pairs from one of the inner maps and the `flatMap` effectively concatenates these lists of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is the same as the others, but uses for-comprehension which is a syntax-sugar for a chain of nested `map`s, `flatMap`s (and `withFilter`s):

```
for {
  (_, innerMap) <- myMap
  (_, app) <- innerMap
} yield (app.token, app)
```

You can read more about it in the [Scala Tour](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html).

The result if of type `Map[String, App]`, assuming `app.token: String`. You had it with `AppKey`, which is probably a typo (or otherwise you had a different intent).

---

As noted by @leo-c, you should take into account that between two pairs in a `Map` that have the same key the latter wins, so if those tokens are not unique, you'll just lose some information. If that's the case, you may want the result to have type `Map[String, List[AppKey]]` to group all apps with the same token. You can get it with this code:

```
val apps = myMap.values.flatMap(_.values)
val result = apps.groupBy(_.token)
```

See documentation for the [`groupBy`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]) method.